# Distributional solution to xf'=0

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

In chapter XII of Hilbert Space, Boundary Value Problems, and Orthogonal Polynomials, By Allan M. Krall.

Gives the example that the solution to $$xf'=0$$ is $$f=c+dH(x)$$ where H(x) is the Heaviside function.

I can't seem to find a proof of this example. Could someone write one here or link me to a complete proof?

Comment: Have you tried to prove it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_H$ be the regular distribution corresponding to $H$. Then for $\phi\in C_0^\infty$ we have
$$
T_H'\phi = -T_H\phi' = -\int H(x)\phi'(x)\,dx = -\int_0^\infty\phi'(x)\,dx = \phi(0) = \delta\phi.
$$
Hence, $T_H' = \delta$, or shorter, $H' = \delta$. From $xf'=0$ you know that $f' = c\delta = (cH)'$. Thus, $f = cH + d$.

Comment: $xf'\implies f'=c\delta$ follows from $\phi-\phi(0)\psi = x\Phi$

Comment: @reuns OP knew that already. Look at their last comment.